# How can we increase Cloud Anchors expire time from 24 hours

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, augmented-reality, arcore

I am currently working on Cloud Anchor ARCore project. I came to know that  Cloud Anchors expire after 24 hours. Is there any way to increase this expiry time period?

Comment: No. https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/ios/overview